# (Approximation) Algorithms for Weight Distribution / Subspace Weights Problem in coding theory

Tags: complexity-theory, linear-algebra, hamming-code

The Weight Distribution / Subspace Weights Problem in coding theory is defined as this: 
Instance: A binary $m$ by$n$ matrix $H$ and an integer $k > 0$ 
Question: Is there a set of $k$ columns of $H$ that sum to the all-zero vector?

You might also say: 
Given a binary $m$ by$n$ matrix $H$ and an integer $k > 0$, is there a vector $\vec{x}$, s.t.
$$
A\vec{x} = \vec{0}
$$
where $\vec{x}$ has Hamming Weight k?

This Problem is proven to be NP-complete ([On the Inherent Intractability of Certain Codiig Problems](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1055873)). But is there any fast (polynomial) exact (for small inputs) or approximation algorithm to solve the problem? 
So far I wasn't able to find one.

Comment: Since it is NP-complete, there is unlikely to be any polynomial-time exact algorithm.  I suspect you already know that, so perhaps you really mean to ask about approximation algorithms?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/421000/37212, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/150978/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is called the [low-weight codeword problem](https://decodingchallenge.org/low-weight).  Searching on this will turn up [a number of research papers](https://decodingchallenge.org/home/documentation#hardness) with algorithms for this problem.